# PHP Enviar imágenes en el servidor a un email

Tags: php, phpmailer

Como puedo enviar imágenes que se encuentran en mi servidor a uno o más correos usando PHP.

Leí un poco en ingles que con phpMailer pero no me quedo claro.

Gracias por la ayuda que me puedan prestar

Answer (score 1):

Efectivamente PHPMailer es una buena opción. [Aquí](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) tienes la documentación. Básicamente necesitarás tener un correo que permita conexiones SMTP (Hay otros modos, pero SMTP es muy extendido). Como servidor de correo puedes usar mismamente uno de gmail que tengas (pero casi todos permiten smtp). [Aquí](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=es) tienes la documentación de google de cómo configurar la conexión por SMTP (seguramente tengas que activarlo desde tu gmail). Te pongo ejemplo de código:

```
   <?php
       require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

       $mail = new PHPMailer;

       $mail->isSMTP(); //Aqui le decimos que es SMTP
       $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
       $mail->SMTPAuth = true;// Necesitas autenticarte con tu correo
       $mail->Username = 'tuemail@gmail.com';
       $mail->Password = 'passworddelemail';
       $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; //Aqui le indicas si necesita TLS y el puerto
       $mail->Port = 587;



       $mail->setFrom('tuemail@gmail.com', 'Email de From');
       $mail->addAddress('emaila@mail.com', 'Nombre');
       $mail->addReplyTo('tuemail@gmail.com', 'Email de respuesta');
       $mail->addCC('a@mail.com'); //Si quieres añadir CC
       $mail->addBCC('b@mail.com'); //Si quieres añadir BCC

       //Con addAttachment podemos añadir attachments
       $mail->addAttachment('path/to/file');
       $mail->addAttachment('path/to/file');

       //Indicamos que el cuerpo del mensaje va a ser un html
       $mail->isHTML(true);

       $mail->Subject = 'Asunto del email';
       $mail->Body    = 'Cuerpo del mensaje en HTML';
       $mail->AltBody = 'Cuerpo del mensaje en texto por si el receptor no puede ver HTML (opcional)';

       //Enviamos email
       if(!$mail->send()) {
           //Mensaje no pudo ser enviado
       } else {
           //Mensaje enviado correctamente
       }
```

(No he probado el código asi que puede tener typos)